# How do I print one JSON stanza from a JSON file in the linux terminal

Tags: json, jq

I have a JSON file and it has data like this,

```
{  
  "key": "SEA-739",
  "status": "Open",
  "assignee": null
}
{
  "key": "SEA-738",
  "status": "Resolved",
  "assignee": "user2@mycompany.com"
}
```

From the above file, I need to extract only one JSON stanza that I intend to evaluate/test. Expected output,

```
{  
  "key": "SEA-739",
  "status": "Open",
  "assignee": null
}
```